# Using Brasero with two cd drives

Tags: cd, brasero

When using Brasero I would like to use both drives. One for the blank media and the other with the media I would like to copy. When I open Brasero it seems to insist that I change media regardless of which drive I start out with. Please include details, Ubuntu is new to me.

Comment: Well, you could give `k3b` a try. Usually works with two drives. But k3b can also fail with that, depending on the OS, and the OS update level.